# What are consequences if you hit the governor limit for monthly Platform event delivery limit?

Tags: platform-event

My client has Salesforce Performance edition. From Salesforce documentation, I understood that the maximum limit to deliver the number of Platform Events per month is 1.5million. I want to understand what are the consequences from Salesforce if the maximum delivery of platform event notification is already reached in the mid of the month. Would the subsequent Platform Events be not delivered? OR will Salesforce charge client to deliver the Platform events which are exceeding the monthly limit?
Please let me know.

Thanks and Regards,
Kedar

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the [client's subscription](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm).

By default, the limits simply cannot be exceeded:

> If your org has no add-on licenses, default allocations apply and can't be exceeded. ... If you exceed the default event delivery allocation, you receive an error.

If your client has purchased the addon upgrade:

> ...your allocation for delivered events to CometD clients moves to a monthly entitlement model. ... The entitlement is not as strictly enforced as the default allocation. With the entitlement, you can exceed your 24-hour event delivery allocation by a certain amount.

And they're still not automatically billed for overages:

> Salesforce monitors event overages based on a calendar month, starting with your contract start date. If you exceed the monthly entitlement, Salesforce contacts you to discuss your event usage needs.

So, it would be worth discussing with the account executive if there's a concern. Note that even though they're listed as "monthly" limits, these limits are subdivided into days, so it's not like you'll have a situation where you need to wait more than 24 hours before you can use more events.

You should read the entire documentation (above) for more details, including examples of how the limits are enforced.